# CodeIgniter anchor function without any string in value

Tags: codeigniter

My code right now:

```
<?php echo anchor('admin/delete_msg/'.$obj->id, 'DELETE MESSAGE', array('onclick' => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');', 'class' => 'delete-button')); ?>
```

But  Iwould liek to use something like:

```
<?php echo anchor('admin/delete_msg/'.$obj->id, '', array('onclick' => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');', 'class' => 'delete-button')); ?>
```

So there is no "DELETE MESSAGE" text and I can use image instead.

But if I leave the single quotes empty the link will show up e.g. `http://localhost/project`

Any advice how to solve that within anchor function and not going via `<a href="...`?

Comment: The whole point of an anchor is to have something to anchor _to_. You'll need to pass in something for an anchor, and that could include a `<img/>` tag element, or just use CSS to hide your default anchor text and replace with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it using space like:

```
<?php echo anchor('admin/delete_msg/'.$obj->id, ' ', array('onclick' => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');', 'class' => 'delete-button')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to hide the text and pull in a background image:

```
.delete-button{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80px; /* fits background-img width */
   height: 40px; /* fits background-img height */
   text-indent: -9999px;
   background: url('path/to/image') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the anchor helper. Just pass $obj to the view(html.php)

```
<a rel="nofollow" onclick="return confirm()" class="btn btn-delete-icon" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_msg/'.$obj->id.'')?>"> &nbsp; </a>
```